# jq raw json output carriage return?

Tags: json, bash, shell, jq

Feel free to edit the title; not sure how to word it.  I'm trying to turn shell output into JSON data for a reporting system I'm writing for work.  Quick question, no matter what i do, when I take raw input in slurp mode and output the JSON, the last item in the array is blank ("").  I feel like this is some sort of rookie `jq` issue I'm running into, but can't figure out how to word the issue.  This seems to happen no matter what command I run on the shell and pipe to `jq`:

```
# rpm -qa | grep kernel | jq -R -s 'split("\n")'
[
  "kernel-2.6.32-504.8.1.el6.x86_64",
  "kernel-firmware-2.6.32-696.20.1.el6.noarch",
  "kernel-headers-2.6.32-696.20.1.el6.x86_64",
  "dracut-kernel-004-409.el6_8.2.noarch",
  "abrt-addon-kerneloops-2.0.8-43.el6.x86_64",
  "kernel-devel-2.6.32-358.11.1.el6.x86_64",
  "kernel-2.6.32-131.4.1.el6.x86_64",
  "kernel-devel-2.6.32-696.20.1.el6.x86_64",
  "kernel-2.6.32-696.20.1.el6.x86_64",
  "kernel-devel-2.6.32-504.8.1.el6.x86_64",
  "libreport-plugin-kerneloops-2.0.9-33.el6.x86_64",
  ""
]
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Every line ends with a newline. Either remove the final newline, or omit the empty element at the end of the array.

```
vnix$ printf 'foo\nbar\n' |
> jq -R -s '.[:-1] | split("\n")'
[
  "foo",
  "bar"
]

vnix$ printf 'foo\nbar\n' |
> jq -R -s 'split("\n")[:-1]'
[
  "foo",
  "bar"
]
```

The notation `x[:-1]` retrieves the value of a string or array `x` with the last element removed.  This is called ["slice notation".](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Array/StringSlice:.[10:15])

Just to spell this out, if you take the string `"foo\n"` and split on newline, you get `"foo"` from before the newline and `""` after it.

To make this really robust, maybe trim the last character only if it really is a newline.

```
vnix$ printf 'foo\nbar\n' |
> jq -R -s 'sub("\n$";"") | split("\n")'
[
  "foo",
  "bar"
]

vnix$ printf 'foo\nbar' |
> #  notice, no final ^ newine
> jq -R -s 'sub("\n$";"") | split("\n")'
[
  "foo",
  "bar"
]
```

Comment: I get that and know that by doing `rpm -qa | grep kernel | od -c`; happens everytime.  I'm asking how to solve it via `jq` or any other method.  Your answer didn't really "spell it out".  If you could assist with what I need to pass to `jq` to omit the empty element at the end of the array, that would be great.  Thanks!

Comment: Added two examples.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you have access to jq 1.5 or later, you can circumvent the problem entirely and economically using `inputs`:

```
jq -nR '[inputs]'
```

Just be sure to include the -n option, otherwise the first line will go missing.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use

```
rpm -qa | grep kernel | jq -R . | jq -s .
```

to get the desired result.

Please see https://github.com/stedolan/jq/issues/563